# Add style to class if it is in use & remove if class isn't in use

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navbar class that is not fixed and a navbar-fixed class that is position fixed and I want the title-img class to have a margin-top of 20% when the navbar-fixed class is being used but not when the navbar class is being used. I tried using JS but couldn't figure out how to remove the margin-top 20% when navbar is being used. (sorry for the long CSS file I wasn't sure if any of my other styles were affecting each other).

```js
const navigationMenu = document.querySelector(".navigation-menu");
const body = document.body;
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.links');
const linksContainer = navigationMenu.querySelector('ul');
const links = linksContainer.querySelectorAll('.link');

// Toggle navigation menu and related elements
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.matches('.top, .middle, .bottom, .links')) {
    hamburger.classList.toggle('active');
    navigationMenu.classList.toggle('active');
    body.classList.toggle('active');
  } else if (!event.target.closest('.navigation-menu')) {
    closeNavigation();
  }
});

// Handle link clicks and smooth scrolling
linksContainer.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const link = event.target.closest('.link');
  if (link) {
    event.preventDefault();
    smoothScroll(link.getAttribute('href'));
    closeNavigation();
  }
});

// Smooth scrolling function
function smoothScroll(targetSelector) {
  const target = document.querySelector(targetSelector);
  if (target) {
    const topOffset = target.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;
    window.scrollTo({
      top: topOffset,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  }
}

// Close navigation function
function closeNavigation() {
  hamburger.classList.remove('active');
  navigationMenu.classList.remove('active');
  body.classList.remove('active');
}

// Optional: Use NodeList directly without converting to array
links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    smoothScroll(this.getAttribute('href'));
    closeNavigation();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

:root {
  --navbar-height: 95px;
}

body {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  margin: 0;
  /* Reset default margin */
}


/* Styles for the regular .navbar class */

.navbar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: var(--navbar-height);
  box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.4) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* Styles for the .navbar-fixed class */

.navbar-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 5px;
  height: var(--navbar-height);
}


/*hamburger*/

.top,
.middle,
.bottom {
  display: block;
  background: #9a7ede;
  width: 20px;
  height: 4px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  transition: transform 0.16s;
}

.links {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.links.active .top {
  transform: translateY(7px) rotate(45deg);
}

.links.active .middle {
  opacity: 0;
}

.links.active .bottom {
  transform: translateY(-7px) rotate(-45deg);
}


/*end of hamburger */

.company-logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

.search {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navigation-menu {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.175s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  top: var(--navbar-height);
  z-index: 1;
}

.navbar-fixed~.navigation-menu {
  top: var(--navbar-height);
  position: fixed;
}

.link {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #9a7ede;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.link:hover {
  color: #0077ee;
}

.linkli {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2c2c2c14;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 2.5% 0 2.5% 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.navigation-menu.active {
  transform: translateX(0);
  z-index: 2;
}

body.active {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.chevron::before {
  content: "\203A";
  font-size: 30px;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0;
  color: #9a7ede;
}


/*end of navigation */


/*end of navbar*/


/* New styles for the main content */

.main-body {
  padding-top: var(--navbar-height);
  /* Adjust the value as needed */
  background-color: #9a7ede;
}

.title-img {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.section {
  margin-top: var(--navbar-height);
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.bg-w {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.bg-p {
  background-color: #9a7ede;
}

.inner-section-wrap {
  margin: 5% 10% 0 10%;
}

.long-img {
  width: 100%;
}

.reg-img {
  height: 150px;
}

.logo-img {
  width: 25px;
}

.content-wrap {
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.s-txt {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.m-txt {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.l-txt {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.purp {
  color: #9a7ede;
}

.centertxt {
  text-align: center;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.map-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  /* Set a maximum width to ensure responsiveness */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Hide any content that overflows the container */
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.scrollable-container {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  /* Apply smooth scrolling to this container */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>test</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@200;300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main copy.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar-fixed">
    <div class="links">
      <span class="top"></span>
      <span class="middle"></span>
      <span class="bottom"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="company-logo">
      <img src="#">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation-menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="linkli"><a rel="noreferrer" target="_self" href="#about" class="link">About Us</a>
        <p class="chevron"></p>
      </li>
      <li class="linkli"><a rel="noreferrer" target="_self" href="#contact" class="link">Contact</a>
        <p class="chevron"></p>
      </li>
      <li class="linkli"><a href="#" class="link">Online Store</a>
        <p class="chevron"></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="scrollable-container">
    <div class="main-body">
      <img class="title-img" src="#">
      <div class="section bg-w">
        <img class="long-img" src="#">
        <div class="inner-section-wrap">
          <div class="centertxt">
            <p id="about" class="m-txt bold purp">About Us</p>
          </div>
          <p class="s-txt purp">placeholder
          </p>
          <div class="content-wrap">
            <img class="reg-img" src="#">
            <img class="reg-img" src="#">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="main copy.js" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution. Comments are added where necessary inside the codes.

```js
const nav_check = document.querySelector('.nav-check');
const title_img = document.querySelector('.title-img');

// Checking if the navbar-fixed class is present
if(nav_check.classList.contains('navbar-fixed')){
    // When present adding the margin to the "title-img" class
    title_img.style.marginTop = '20%';
};
```

```html
<!-- Add a class "nav-check" where the "navbar" and "navbar-fixed" classes are switched -->
<div class="navbar-fixed nav-check">
.....
</div>
```